# Installing Windows 7 and Windows 8 in same partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, operating-systems, multi-boot, windows-installation

I have Windows 7 installed on my pc. In c:\  I want to install Wwindows 8 on the same drive as I have created the partition size as 350 Gb. I want to keep both Windows installations on the same partition.

I was wondering that Is it possible?

Comment: Installing it on the same partition is a bad idea and won't work.

Comment: In same partition it is not possible.

Comment: Not possible on the same partition.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to extend or new primary partition if you want dual boot windows7 and windows 8. This is not possible on same partition.

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't work. If you use Win8 Pro you can install it into a VHD and boot from it.

Follow the Guide of Scott Hanselman:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply i had it installed in my extended logical partition it works. I know the installation of windows in VHD . the deal is to install it in same partition like we can do it in windows xp or on older version of windows